# How does this trick expose the Python library by removing the C one? (allows monkeypatching ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-import

I wanted to monkeypatch ElementTree, because it is too limited and I have a block of code that works but I don't understand it, so could be dangerous (cross-platform? Version issues? Depracated? Python4 compatibility? etc.), so I would like to understand it.

`ElementTree.Element` cannot be easily monkeypatched as it is implemented in C (see footnote), but "exposing the hidden Python module works". This following chunk of code is from the module `xmlschema`, which accidentally and magically placed before an import for ElementTree make the imported `ElementTree.Element` monkeypatchable.
The reason why is this chunk of code:

```
import sys, importlib
sys.modules.pop('xml.etree.ElementTree', None)
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
ET = importlib.import_module('xml.etree.ElementTree')
```

So the module is getting remove from the system. But then importlib imports it anyway.

The documentation says:

> The most important difference between these two functions is that import_module() returns the specified package or module (e.g. pkg.mod), while **import**() returns the top-level package or module (e.g. pkg).

But I am not specifying a package...

- Does importlib not check in the dictionary sys.modules?
- Is this trick universally safe or is it dangerous? (works on Mac py 3.7 where `import lxml` fails and Win 3.4 where it works)

### C-implemented ET.element footnote

This is an example of inability to monkeypatch ET.Element.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.Element.new = 'anything'
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'
class newElement(ET.Element):
    new = 'hello world'
>>> ET.Element = newElement
>>> elem = ET.fromstring('<xml><hello>world</hello></xml>')
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'new'
>>> type(newElement()) # should be
>>> type(elem) # but isn't
```